# Python openCV find image in folder of images(road sign recognition)

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, template-matching

I'm doing road sign recognition program. I've successfuly done with image preprocesing. I have extracted image of road sign.

Now I don't know what algorithem or template matching should I use to find matching image of my extracted image.

Solution must be simple and effective, because I'm still learning Python.

1.image: extracted image     2. image: matched image

[image: Extracted image][image: That image sould find algorithm in folder of images]

Answer (score 0):

Template matching doesn't work in your case. Template matching works only with nearly the same template in your source. 
I propose to use `dlib`
http://dlib.net/ml.html for deep learning.
It's easy to learn and you don't need write a lot of code. If you still want to use template matching you could try following:

```
import cv2

source = cv2.imread("/source/of/your_stop_sign")
template = cv2.imread("our/template")
(tempH, tempW) = template.shape[:2]
```

try to find the template:

```
result = cv2.matchTemplate(source, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
(minVal, maxVal, minLoc, (x, y)) = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)
```

draw the bounding box

```
cv2.rectangle(source, (x, y), (x + tempW, y + tempH), (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

show the result

```
cv2.imshow("source", source)
cv2.imshow("template", template)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: Template]
[image: Source]
[image: Result]